# How to install phpmyadmin my on subdomain of nginx server

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

I want to install phpmyadmin on a subdomain of nginx web server. If anyone could guide me it would be helpful

Comment: Maybe this can be a guide https://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/DevOps_phpMyAdmin_Nginx_Subdomain.php

Comment: Not working @darius.v

Comment: I think you should add more detail - like are you getting some errors. How does your nginx config look.

Answer (score 0):

@darius.v I did it perfectly. I created Symbolic Links from installation directory to /var/www then added a config in site available to point to subdomain and created Symbolic Link to site enabled that's it!!